# Infinite stuck on CompletableFuture.allOf().get()

Tags: java, multithreading, completable-future, fork-join

I need to execute one function 50 times in parallel, but smth goes wrong:

1. After the line

```
CompletableFuture.allOf(deviationsFutures).get();
```

nothing happens, always stuck on it forever. So lines "BBBBB" are never print.

2. Why do I have ~ 20 lines "AAAAAAAAAA" in my logs before the debugger entered the line

```
CompletableFuture.allOf(deviationsFutures).get();
```

?
After that, ~ 30 more lines appear.
However, here are not memory leaks or even memory usage increasing, according to VisualVM.

What am I doing wrong?

Cal the function:

```
 CompletableFuture<Void>[] deviationsFutures = new CompletableFuture[50];
    List<DeviationSumByW> deviations = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

    int index = 0;
  
    for (int w = 2; w <= 50; w++) {
      CompletableFuture<Void> deviationFuture =
          createFutureTaskComputingDeviationByW(daysLastYear, dayRows, metricAlias, w)
              .thenAcceptAsync(
                  deviationSumByW -> {
                    System.out.println(
                        "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA");
                    deviations.add(deviationSumByW);
                  });

      deviationsFutures[index++] = deviationFuture;
    }

    try {
      CompletableFuture.allOf(deviationsFutures).get();
      System.out.println(
          "BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB");
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
      LOGGER.error("Exception while CompletableFuture.allOf(deviationsFutures).get()", e);
    }

    return (long)
        deviations.stream()
            .min(Comparator.comparing(DeviationSumByW::getwDeviationSum))
            .orElse(DeviationSumByW.DEFAULT)
            .getW();
```

The function:

```
 private CompletableFuture<DeviationSumByW> createFutureTaskComputingDeviationByW(
      List<TimestampWithMetrics> daysLastYear,
      List<TimestampWithMetrics> dayRows,
      String metricAlias,
      int w) {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
        () -> {
          long wDeviationSum = 0;

          for (TimestampWithMetrics rowDay : daysLastYear) {
            List<TimestampWithMetrics> rowsSameDayOfWeek =
                dayRows.stream()
                    .filter(
                        dayTimestamp ->
                            dayTimestamp
                                .getTimestamp()
                                .getDayOfWeek()
                                .equals(rowDay.getTimestamp().getDayOfWeek()))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

            long aCurrent =
                rowDay.getMetricsWithParams().stream()
                    .filter(metric -> metric.getMetricAlias().equalsIgnoreCase(metricAlias))
                    .findFirst()
                    .orElse(new MetricWithParams())
                    .getCurrent();
            wDeviationSum +=
                Math.abs(
                    aCurrent - findProfileByDateAndW(w, rowsSameDayOfWeek, rowDay, metricAlias));
          }

          return new DeviationSumByW(wDeviationSum, w);
        },
        forkJoinPool);
  }
```

Comment: Note that `ArrayList` is not thread-safe and you are trying to add elements to it in `thenAcceptAsync` of multiple `CompletableFuture`s

Comment: @dan1st good point, thx

Comment: Do you have any blocking operations except `CompletableFuture.allOf(deviationsFutures).get();`? How did you construct the `ForkJoinPool`? Did you use `commonPool()`?

Comment: Do you have two `null` elements in `deviationsFutures`? The array has a size of `50` but you loop from `2` to `50` instead of `1` to `50`.

Comment: @dan1st no, I haven't. ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool(30); But I tried wo/ manually set pool, still same problem

Comment: @dan1st **[2-50]** is just business logic, so i have 1 null element

Comment: Can you try it without null elements? `CompletableFuture.allOf` doesn't seem to like null elements (in my case, it is throwing a NPE).

Comment: @dan1st thx you very much, after set array size to 49, all work well. Still doesn't understand why here wasn't exception in my case and infinite stuck instead of method interrupting. However, question#2 is still actuall. My thoughts are bug with displaying/debugger/Intellij IDEA.

Comment: What java version do you use? This might have changed.

Comment: For #2, are you confused by the ~20 lines printed before reaching the `get()` line in the debugger? What would you expect instead?

Comment: @DidierL, I expect all of lines printed **after** .get(), 'cause the .thenAcceptAsync() must be run only after .createFutureTaskComputingDeviationByW() , that run after .get(). But in my case it seems .thenAcceptAsync() runs before I trigger async run with .get().

Answer (score 0):

For future readers.

1. Infinite stuck

Problem was in the size.

```
CompletableFuture<Void>[] deviationsFutures = new CompletableFuture[50];
```

I had one **null** element, so allOf() had must throw NPE, but did not do it.